# onLongPressGesture makes list item not scrollable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

I have a `List` and want to make list items respond to long press gesture. But after adding the gesture to list item, I can not scroll the list from the text area.

```swift
List {
  ForEach(items) { item in
    Text(item.name)
      .onLongPressGesture { print("long press") }
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440283/longpress-and-list-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should publish more code....

I just tested it with 13.2 ...with this code -> works

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(UIFont.familyNames, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
              .onLongPressGesture { print("long press") }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, try put the finger at text and scroll.

Comment: do you expect scrolling after long press, when you swipe down after long press without lifting your finger!?

Comment: Oh I meant when you start your scroll from the text it won't work.