# How can I make a NavigationLink with TapGesture and LongPressGesture working simultaneously together in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is it possible to have both a NavigationView link coexist with a tap gesture (onLongPressGesture)!?

I can not make it work for the life of me...

```
ScrollView {   
                
    ForEach(self.itemStore.items) { p in
                    
        NavigationLink(destination: Details(p: p)) {

            CardDetector(p: p, position: self.position)
                    
        }
                    
    }

}

struct CardDetector: View {

    var p: ListData

    @State var position: CardPosition

    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
    
        Group {

        switch position {
            
            case .small:
                
                smallcardView(p: p, namespace: namespace)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 120)
                    .background(BlurView(style: .regular))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.vertical,6)
                    .onLongPressGesture {
                    
                        withAnimation {
                        
                            position = .big
                    
                        }
                
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
```

This causes issues with scrolling... which they say the solution is to add a `onTapGesture` (according to the answer: [Longpress and list scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440283/longpress-and-list-scrolling)) but then the `NavigationLink` wont work!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to separate link with gestures, making link activated programmatically. In such cases actions, gestures, and scrolling do not conflict.

Here is a simplified demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<10) {
                LinkCard(number: $0 + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LinkCard: View {
    let number: Int
    @State private var isActive = false
    @State private var isBig = false

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(height: isBig ? 400 : 100)
            .overlay(Text("Card \(number)"))
            .background(NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("Details \(number)"),
                isActive: $isActive) {
                EmptyView()
            })
            .onTapGesture {
                isActive.toggle()    // << activate link !!
            }
            .onLongPressGesture {
                isBig.toggle()       // << alterante action !!
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can this be done with a scrollview as well or should list be used exclusively?  I will try your solution soon... I hope it works for my use case!

Comment: i get the following error `Missing argument for the parameter #1 in call - insert '<#LocalizedStringKey#>'` with the `.background(NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("Details \(number)"),
                isActive: $isActive) {
                EmptyView()
            })`

Comment: So i just put a unique string to satisfy the error but your solution WORKED!!! Man you never disappoint!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a complicated project to explain, but I try: for having possibility to direct link to a View not just like a simple `String` or `Text`, I defined Content type which conform to View protocol in our `Item` struc. So you can link any View that you already designed.

For making tap actually be able open the Link we should work on custom Binding.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var items: [Item] = [Item(stringValue: "Link 0", destination: Text("Destination 0").foregroundColor(Color.red)),
                                        Item(stringValue: "Link 1", destination: Text("Destination 1").foregroundColor(Color.green)),
                                        Item(stringValue: "Link 2", destination: Text("Destination 2").foregroundColor(Color.blue))]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                
                ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self ) { index in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: items[index].destination , isActive: Binding.init(get: { () -> Bool in return items[index].isActive },
                                                                                                  set: { (newValue) in items[index].isActive = newValue })) {
                        
                        Color.white.opacity(0.01)
                            .overlay(Text(items[index].stringValue), alignment: .leading)
                            .onTapGesture { items[index].isActive.toggle(); print("TapGesture! on Index:", index.description) }
                            .onLongPressGesture { print("LongPressGesture! on Index:", index.description) }
                        

                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

---

```
struct Item<Content: View>: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var stringValue: String
    var isActive: Bool = Bool()
    var destination: Content
}
```

Comment: @Learn2Code: the answer got updated, now everything works!