# How to implement long press gesture on items within a list using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to implement a **long press gesture** on each item within a list using **SwiftUI**.
The final goal is similar to the email app on iPhone - you can swipe up and down to browse, you can swipe left and delete an item, and you can long press an email and do something else.

With SwiftUI, after implementing the long press gesture for each item, I can't swipe the list at all. It seems like the long press gesture on each item is canceling the swipe actions

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm updating the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440283/longpress-and-list-scrolling) as it has some significant delays (more than what you would expect from a long press gesture) when long-pressed. So to mitigate this, you can use `onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration:)` to set a duration you are comfortable with.

See the example below

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<100) { x in
        Text("List number -\(x)")
            .onTapGesture {}.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2) { // Setting the minimumDuration to ~0.2 reduces the delay
                print("long press \(x)")
            }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It is important to have both `.onTapGesture {}.onLongPressGesture{}` one after the other. The above will not work otherwise.

Comment: I used .gesture(longPress) and implement the longPress, while you used .onTapGesture and .onLongPressGesture. at the same time. I tested it out that you have to keep them both, onTapGesture and onLongPressGesture, in order to have both swipe and long press working at the same time

Comment: Yes, sorry If I had not made it clear, let me add it into the answer