# OnLongPressGesture blocks ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I got a `ScrollView` and a `View` inside that has a `onLongPressGesture`. Because the Item inside the `ScrollView` is full width it blocks the scrolling.

```
ScrollView {
    MessageBubble()
}
```

```
struct MessageBubble: View {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("message")
                .frame(width: width)
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1) {
                    // Do something here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything helpful since most other asked questions regarding this have the `TapGesture` for the `ScrollView` and `onLongPressGesture` in the same View.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longpress and list scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440283/longpress-and-list-scrolling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `onTapGesture` should solve your problem:

```
struct MessageBubble: View {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("message")
                .frame(width: width)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // do nothing just allow the scroll view to receive touches
                }
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1) {
                    // Do something here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh so it is the same fix like for drag gesture, even when it is in another View